# Receive memory warning when creating a lot of view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

Anyone can help me the solution for this issue

My code :

```
NSMutableArray *listVC = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
HMScrollView *scrollView = [[HMScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.showView.bounds];

for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.count; i ++) {
    self.theNewDetailViewController = [[NewDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.theNewDetailViewController.abmObj = (AboutUS_MobileService*)[newsArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [self.theNewDetailViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(2, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width-4, scrollView.frame.size.height)];

    [listVC addObject:self.theNewDetailViewController];


    [self addChildViewController:self.theNewDetailViewController];
    [self.theNewDetailViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

[scrollView setData:listVC atIndex:index];
[self.showView addSubview:scrollView];
[self.showView bringSubviewToFront:self.imageHeader];
```

Answer (score 0):

No device has an infinite memory capacity, so you need to be careful in your scenario here. iOS is just telling you that its low on memory. Probably because you are allocating too much memory for your view controllers. You should use the Instruments memory profiler to see where you are spending the memory. Instruments will tell you how big your view controllers are. You can then decide where you need to invest your time optimizing (less views or lighter weight views).

Have you considered using a UITableView/UICollectionView for displaying this content. Using table views and collection views you can display a lists of content (similar to a scroll view) but can also be clever about memory use with tricks like lazy loading and cell reuse.

Comment: Tks Sanjit for your support